# Adding a related item using get_or_create in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to `get_or_create` a related record in django 1.8 as follows:

In models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class ScanItem(models.Model):
    # Stock code
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Scan(models.Model):
    # Date of scan
    d = models.DateField(primary_key=True, default=datetime.date.today)
    item = models.ForeignKey(ScanItem, related_name='scan_related_scanitem',null=True)
```

My code:

```
import datetime

# Todays date
d=datetime.date.today()

# Get or create a 'Scan' for today
scan_object, scan_object_created = Scan.objects.get_or_create(
               d__exact=d,
               defaults={'d': d, }
)

# Add an item, relate it to 'Scan'
code = "ABCDEF001"
i, i_created = ScanItem.objects.get_or_create(
               code__exact=code, 
               scan_related_scanitem__exact=scan_object,
               defaults={
                   'scan_related_scanitem': scan_object,
                   'code': code, 
               }
)
```

When i run this, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'scan_related_scanitem' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

How do I specify the default for the `ScanItem` as it needs to be linked to the `Scan` ?

Comment: I didnot check the correctness of fields, but in these cases, you dont need `defaults` since they are already in args

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, Scan doesn't have an attribute `scan_related_item`. That's the *related* name, for the link back from ScanItem to Scan. The forwards relationship uses the actual field name, just like any other field.

Answer (score 0):

The foreignkey should have been on the `ScanItem` object instead of `Scan`